# mysql, changing tables from myisam to ndb

Tags: mysql, myisam, ndbcluster

Gents,
  Converting a table from myisam to ndb via:

```
ALTER TABLE piwik_log_profiling ENGINE NDBCLUSTER;
```

This will fail with:

```
BLOB column 'query' can't be used in key specification with the used table type
```

Now, if the 'query' field is changed from text to varchar, then I get the following:

```
Incorrect prefix key; the used key part isn't a string, the used length is longer than the key part, or the storage engine doesn't support unique prefix keys
```

Original table:

```
| log_profiling_backup | CREATE TABLE `log_profiling_backup` (
`query` text NOT NULL,
`count` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`sum_time_ms` float DEFAULT NULL,
UNIQUE KEY `query` (`query`(100))
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |
```

Comment: Changing the index to 'normal' fixes this... but... is that the safest thing to do?  I am not a mysql expert.  :)  Thanks!

Comment: I guess the question here is... whats the safest change that you can do to the table to be ndb-compliant :)
THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could try the following:

```
ALTER TABLE piwik_log_profiling RENAME piwik_log_profiling_old;
CREATE TABLE piwik_log_profiling SELECT * FROM piwik_log_profiling_old WHERE 1=2;
ALTER TABLE piwik_log_profiling ADD COLUMN query100 CHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER query;
ALTER TABLE piwik_log_profiling ADD UNIQUE INDEX (query100);
ALTER TABLE piwik_log_profiling ENGINE=NDBCLUSTER;
```

If it works up to now, them do this

```
INSERT INTO piwik_log_profiling (query)
SELECT query,LEFT(query,100),`count`,sum_time_ms
FROM piwik_log_profiling_old;
```

Based on this, your queries will have to use query100 instead of query in its WHERE clauses.

Please let us all know if this worked !!!