# Unable to Convert table Engine from MyISAM to NDBCLUSTER

Tags: mysql, storage-engine

I followed @RolandoMySQLDBA 's tips in this thread: [mysql, changing tables from myisam to ndb](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/14034/mysql-changing-tables-from-myisam-to-ndb)  But I didn't succeed on the last step.

I have a similar problem, here's my original table:

```
CREATE TABLE `df_modules_metadata_values` (
  `id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `uid` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `share_id` mediumint(9) DEFAULT NULL,
  `file_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `field_id` mediumint(9) NOT NULL,
  `val` text CHARACTER SET utf8,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date_added` (`date_added`),
  KEY `uid` (`uid`,`file_id`,`field_id`),
  KEY `file_id` (`file_id`,`field_id`),
  KEY `uid_2` (`uid`,`field_id`),
  KEY `val` (`val`(100)),
  KEY `field_id` (`field_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

If I simply convert it, it will give me this error:

```
mysql> alter table df_modules_metadata_values engine=ndbcluster;
ERROR 1073 (42000): BLOB column 'val' can't be used in key specification with the used table type
```

Here is what I tried:

```
mysql> show table status where name='df_modules_metadata_values';
+----------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                       | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| df_modules_metadata_values | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |    0 |              0 |           0 | 281474976710655 |         2048 |         0 |              1 | 2017-09-10 18:00:21 | 2017-09-10 18:00:21 | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci |     NULL |                |         |
+----------------------------+--------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> alter table df_modules_metadata_values rename df_modules_metadata_values_old;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> create table df_modules_metadata_values select * from df_modules_metadata_values_old where 1=2;

Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.15 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> alter table df_modules_metadata_values add column val100 char(100) after val;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.39 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> alter table df_modules_metadata_values add unique index (val100);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.33 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

mysql> alter table df_modules_metadata_values engine=ndbcluster;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.49 sec)
Records: 0  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 1

mysql> show table status where name='df_modules_metadata_values';
+----------------------------+------------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                       | Engine     | Version | Row_format | Rows | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free | Auto_increment | Create_time | Update_time | Check_time | Collation         | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------------------+------------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| df_modules_metadata_values | ndbcluster |      10 | Dynamic    |    0 |              0 |           0 |               0 |            0 |         0 |           NULL | NULL        | NULL        | NULL       | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL | partitioned    |         |
+----------------------------+------------+---------+------------+------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+-------------+-------------+------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Now I have difficulty to finalize your last step, I can't understand the meaning of them, how to finish the "insert into" step? And why we need to do that?

What's more, during my operations, I could see some warnings, how can I check them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- After seeing `Warnings: 1`, do `SHOW WARNINGS;`; there could be something important.
- Get rid of `KEY (val(100))`; it is virtually useless anyway.  If you don't need the full size of `TEXT`, make it a reasonably short `VARCHAR`, then have `KEY (val)`, else get rid of the index completely.

Comment: The warning says: Table storage engine 'ndbcluster' does not support the create option 'Binlog of table with BLOB attribute and no PK'. Can we ignore it safety?

Comment: Looks like there is a PK??  I don't understand.

Comment: Thank you, I tried to keep all the types as original as possible. But it seems if I set val to text, I can't add key(val).

Comment: Let's see the query that would make use of `KEY(val(100))`.

Comment: Sorry, how to do that?

Comment: You chose to do `val(100)` for some reason??

Comment: I took your advice and use KEY(val) instead, but still no luck.

Comment: Remove that one KEY so that you can finish the conversion.

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-cluster-limitations-syntax.html : "TEXT and BLOB columns.  You cannot create indexes on NDB table columns that use any of the TEXT or BLOB data types."

Comment: Converting to NDB is a lot more complex than converting to InnoDB.  Can you explain the need for NDB?

Comment: I just want to achieve the high availability. So, in order to build a clustered environment, I must convert storage engine to ndbcluster. Otherwise, the data won't sync eath other.

Comment: Yeah, I have read that document as well, so I use varchar instead of text and it worked. So I think this is a workaround, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to InnoDB is easier than to NDB.  And you can get HA with it.

Since the question seems to be about making a High Availability setups, I recommend (instead of NDB) that you go with "InnoDB Cluster" and "Group Replication".  (Read up on them in the online manual for 5.7.)

That will require conversion to InnoDB on all of your tables and that they have a `PRIMARY KEY`.

[*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/myisam2innodb) further discusses conversion from MyISAM to InnoDB.